# Importing multiple images from Photo Library to App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to create an app that will let you import photos from your Photo Library and insert them into designated UIImageViews. I was able to get this to work for one of the UIImageViews in my interface, but can't get any to assign to the second UIImageView.

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks! SBB

Here is my code:

```
@implementation FlipBook2ViewController


- (IBAction)selectExistingPicture {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Error accessing photo library" 
                              message:@"Device does not support a photo library" 
                              delegate:nil 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}


- (IBAction)selectExistingPicture2 {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Error accessing photo library" 
                              message:@"Device does not support a photo library" 
                              delegate:nil 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}


#pragma mark  -
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    imageView.image = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `imageView` in the delegate method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` isn't changing. You should probably have an instance variable for the current image view, say something like `currentImageView` and them implement the delegate method like,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    currentImageView.image = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

For this to work however you will have to alter your `selectExistingPicture` a bit.

```
- (IBAction)selectExistingPicture {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

        currentImageView = imageView1; // Set it to the image view that will get changed

        [..]
    }
    else {
        [..]
    }
}
```

However you will have to do this for every method. I am not sure what the exact trigger for this method is but it would be appropriate to have the `sender` argument in the action method to avoid repetition.

```
- (IBAction)selectExistingPicture:(id)sender {
    switch(sender.tag) {
        /* set `currentImageView` based on the tag */
    }

    /* Rest of your method from the question remains the same */
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. doesn't seem to work. I have two buttons and two ImageViews that should be populated by the picture selected from the Photo Library when pressing its respective button.